# how to get the following media query to work for 480px?

Tags: html, css, styles, media-queries

I am trying to do the following `css` for media query max width for `480px` but for some strange reason, nothing is working. My other media queries are fine but for this particular query, nothing is being changed. I think the em for `480px` is `30em`? I have included a part of my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}

.nav {
  width: 200%;

}

#nav-icon {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  color:  #ffffff;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

div.nav ul, div.nav li, label{
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 150%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: .9em;
  }

div.header2_welcome h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  right: 0em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image]

@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 979px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}

Comment: nothing to do with php

Comment: apologies.... should just be under html and css

Comment: You need to add the closing bracket `}` for the media query. Also try by changing the orientation of your device.

Comment: It would be great if you share all the related code of html as well.

Comment: I have added the closing bracket of the media query but did not include all the codes because it is  too long..

Comment: its quite possible that some other media query is overriding this one. Most probably a media query with `min-width` parameter. But to be sure, the community needs to see the other relevant code.

Comment: I guess I should use codepen for this

Comment: Is there a quick way to copy the whole code in cpanel? can't find copy all option

Comment: I figured it out but can't get my codepen to save with the url

Answer (score 0):

Use min-width with existing media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px and max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {

}
```

Also check whether any css libraries are overriding your styles. If so try to load this custom css after all other css files

Comment: the strange thing is that it will only work if I used min-width:0px but not max-width anymore but I started with max-width for all the break point

Comment: I used max-width: 1600px, max-width: 1200px, max-width: 768 px

Comment: I got the following information from here but it doesn't have a landscape for tablet

Comment: I can only think that my landscape of 1024px for tablet is affecting it

Comment: This is strange.. one of the breakpoint tester I downloaded for chrome says to use 486px as a max-width for mobile phone but here, it says to use 578px here:

Comment: Can someone confirm this for me? Why doesn't 478px work?

Comment: I think there are two more break points to do then but how would I add orientation: landscape to 578 pixel?

Comment: This is strange because if I add max-width of 578px, then I can also add max-width of 478 pixel

Comment: how would you test the landscape mode in chrome? Is there a say because I think i would set something link @media (max-width: 578) and (orientation: landsccape){} but how would this be tested in chrome?

Comment: I think I might know how to do it

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 578px) and (orientation: landscape){}  will not work for most the devices. Because in landscape mode, device height is considered as its width. So in most of the devices (except iphone 5/SE) this will not work. 

Have you added the meta viewport tag?. If not add one.
If you are using bootstrap 4+, they are using max-width 576px for mobile devices which obviously sounds good.

Comment: so i guess the 576px is for the bigger smart phones whereas the samsung galaxy s5 and earlier would use 478

Comment: I got the following information from bootstrap but am confused because is the landscape mode for tablet set to 1020px or 768 orientation landscape?

Comment: I think I might have done it wrong by setting max-width: 1020 orientation landscape

Comment: I tried using the smartphones with a wider screen but I thought that 578 is for smartphones? It seems to be only responsive to 478px